# migrate Laravel Database using artisan

Tags: php, symfony, laravel, laravel-4

when try to migrate Laravel 4 with table 'user' in database using artisan:

```
php artisan migrate:make --table="user" CreateUserTable
```

I receive this error:

> C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel>php artisan migrate:make --table=user CreateUserTable
>   [21.04.2014 02:27:56 NOTICE] Successfully established connection to the database
>
> [21.04.2014 02:27:56 NOTICE] Event Reporting is not allowed at the
>   moment. Reaso ns: Pre Startup or Post Shutdown
>   {"error":{"type":"Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpExcepti
>   on","message":"","file":"C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\
>   \src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php","line":871}}
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel>

how to solve this?

thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this by install all laravel dependences using composer (not download it from GithHub)

Answer (score 0):

to install all dependencies with composer.
change directory to laravel folder in cmd and than type
composer update
and hit enter and wait until it is done.